# Amenability of finite dimensional norm algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, homology-cohomology, banach-algebras, amenability

Let $(\cal A,\|\cdot\|)$ be a finite dimensional norm algebra (Banach Algebra). Can we say any thing about the amenability of $\cal A$. What if we impose some extra conditions on $\cal A$, say commutativity or the existence of a unit.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Every finite-dimensional Banach algebra should be amenable. You can probably find this in the sources link on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_Banach_algebra).

Comment: @ Rasmus: If it is really easy to show could you tell me how should I start a proof.

Comment: @Rasmus: I guess the answer should be more complicated, as for a finite normed space $X$, one may make a Banach algebra by defining $ab=0$ for every $a,b\in X$ and it is not amenable.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It's nice to see that, apparently, you've found the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer to my question is as follows.

If $A$ is a finite dimensional Banach algebra with a trivial Jacobson radical, then it is amenable. The answer is easily based on this fact that this class of finite dimensional algebras are isomorphic to a product of finitely many $n_i\times n_i$ matrix rings over division rings $D_i$, by Artin–Wedderburn theorem.

Recall that each of this matrix algebras is amenable and a simple argument regarding adjoining the (virtual) diagonals together implies that the product is amenable.

The converse is also true. If $A$ is a finite dimensional Banach algebra with a non-trivial radical, it cannot admit any (virtual) diagonal; hence, it cannot be amenable.